# Связь jQuery и PHP

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здраствуйте!

У меня возникла такая проблема. Вообще такого никогда не видел раньше....

Есть сайт половина из которого написана на jQuery и просто яваскрипте. Теперь у меня стоит задача соединить ява-скриптовую часть с php-кодом. 
Я только начал этим занлиматься как встал в полный ступор. Когда я пишу следующие строчки php-кода (не важно до или после включения в html код jQuery):

```
$db1 = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root_pass');
mysql_select_db ('site_62', $db1);
```

ВСЯ ЧАСТЬ jQuery у меня просто перестает работать. Причем этот код как видите ничего не выводит. А вывод ошибок на сервере отключен (display_errors = Off). Но когда я выбираю базу данных вся часть jQuery перестает работать, а javascript РАБОТАЕТ как работала раньше! Причем если писать этот php-код далее, то он отрабатывает нормально: выбирает нужные записи мне из таблицы. А jquery как бы это странно не звучало начинает работать только если эта часть кода закоменчена. Абсолютно то же самое происходит при добавлении строчки:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Но только здесь одно различие: если во втором аргументе этой функции написать 0, а не 1, то jquery работает, а если написать единицу (т.е. изменить глобальное значение на сервере), то работать он перестает...

Вот как у меня объявлено использование jQuery (делал не я):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modalbox/modalbox.css">

<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/ui/jquery.ui.progressbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/ui/jquery.effects.fold.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.betterTooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.backgroundPosition.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/json.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Если кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой или просто знает, что делать в данной ситуации, что делать, то взываю Вас к помощи! Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Да и еще... Не важно в каком браузере работать. Будь то Opera или Chrome, везде все одинаково!

Comment: А консоль ошибок javascript что пишет?

Comment: Используйте консоль ошибок JS: в опере (F12), в хроме (правой кнопкой -> просмотр кода элемента).

Comment: Умоляю вас, пожалейте пользовтелей и слейте все это в 1 js файл -.-

Comment: Не используй mysql, он старый уже, лучше mysqli, а ещё лучше PDO.

Comment: @Miomoor, извините, вы на дату вопроса обратили внимание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема исправлена. Ошибка была в том, что JavaScript выполнялся до определенного момента. А у меня было так:

```
<div id='actinfo' style="display:none">
JSON-массив
</div>
```

Вот при добавлении той php строчки, вместо json-массива писалась скулевская ошибка, и поэтому javascript не исполнялся после строчки:

```
 var menu = new Object();
            eval_str=$("#actinfo").html();
            eval("menu = "+eval_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, с этим тоже сталкивался, почему-то такая вещь у меня не работала...
Попробуйте эту строчку заменить чистым javascript

```
eval_str = document.getElementById('actinfo').innerHTML;
menu = eval('('+eval_str+')');
```

Comment: EVAL=EVIL... вы написали ужас :)